# How to check all array's elements?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
function getNumber(number, array){
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] == number) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getNumber(3, [5, 6, 3, 8]));
```

Of course it'll return 'false' all the time, because of 'return' except those situations when array[0] == number. And my question is how to continue checking process for all array's element? It's elementary I know, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: Don't return false in your else. Return false outside of the for loop

Comment: If you are trying to determine if the element exists, you can use the `indexOf` method, or the `some` method. If you want to know if every element in the array is equal to the value, you can use the `.every` method.

Comment: A better approach is scrap the whole function. There is an indexOf method on arrays which returns -1 if it is not in the array. You can check if the number is in the array by returning array.indexOf (number) !== -1

Comment: Thank you guys, it's just an exercise to practice my js skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply move the `return false;` statement to the end of the function.

That means if a value is found, then the iteration stops with returning `true`. If not found, then `false` is returned.

```js
function getNumber(number, array){
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] == number) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(getNumber(3, [5, 6, 3, 8]));
```

Comment: This code works as fine as mine. Why you down vote THIS correct answer?

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel, i have not voted you answer down.

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm sure you did not but someone else has downvoted both of our answers even though they are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Return the false value only when you are done checking all of them

```
function getNumber(number, array){
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
if (array[i] == number) {
  return true;
}
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Same as Nina's answer.

Comment: It was easy :) Thank you!

Comment: I answered seconds after Nina's answer, I only saw it after I posted and I was not the one who down voted it. After all, we all share the same goal.

Comment: It is totally unfair to downvote Nina's answer and also quite unfair to downvote mine just because Nina's answer was posted while I was writing mine and I didn't see it.  I upvoted Nina's answer me too because it was first.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move the else and return false at the end of your for, otherwise your first value that doesn't match, will return false. 
Your code should be changed to:

```
function getNumber(number, array){
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] == number) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(getNumber(3, [5, 6, 3, 8]));
```

What you did can be done in this way:

```
var a = [5, 6, 3, 8];
console.log(a.indexOf(3));
```

indexOf will return -1 if the element is not present otherwise the index of the element. Here the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Don't return true after `if (array[i] == number)` just store this array value in any temporary value like `temp = array[i]` when loop executed then you can return value `return k`

Answer (score -1):

If you are targeting modern browsers or Node.js, you can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example) like that:

```
array.some(function(element) { return element === number });
```

Complete example would be:

```js
var check = function(number, array) {
  return array.some(function(element) { return element === number });
}

console.log(check(3, [ 1, 2, 3 ])); // true
console.log(check(5, [ 1, 2, 3 ])); // false
```